# Where are rows created with pytest-postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pytest

I inherited a fast-api project that uses PostgreSQL and pytest-postgresql to provide pytest fixtures to test against PostgreSQL. Out of curiosity I placed some breakpoint() statements in several places after row model creation, and commits(), but before any cleanup. With breakpoint() holding the process, I then looked at the database server to see if I could find the data that was entered with pytest-postgresql. I could find nothing. Where would this data be?

In my conftest.py file, I have the following for pytest-postgresql setup.

```
from pytest_postgresql import factories
...

postgresql_proc = factories.postgresql_proc(
    host="localhost",
    user="REDACTED",
    port="5432",
    password="REDACTED",
)
pg_fixture = factories.postgresql("postgresql_proc", db_name="REDACTED")

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def db_session(pg_fixture):
    """
    A session object to a non persistent db.
    Will clean up the database after each test run, in its cleanup stage
    """
    sqlalchemy_uri = (
        f"postgresql://{pg_fixture.info.user}:{pg_fixture.info.password}@"
        f"{pg_fixture.info.host}:{pg_fixture.info.port}"
        f"/{pg_fixture.info.dbname}"
    )
    engine = get_engine(sqlalchemy_uri)
    models.base.Base.metadata.create_all(engine) # CREATES VARIOUS MODELS
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    yield Session()
    models.base.Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

The tests work, so I assume that its setup correctly. And by work pass when they should and fail when they should not. But for the life of me I can not understand where pytest-postgresql is putting the row data inserted with the model creation in test setup.

Comment: If the fixture uses an open transaction to run the test, you won't see anything in the database.

Comment: Did you check for any temporary test tables?

Comment: @KlausD. I don't believe it is. I know that transactions can be used with this, but there are commit statements (ORM statement) that I believe commits the transaction. Then later queries can be done against the data that was committed. Clearly there's more than that going on, or at least in with the project I inherited.

Do you use pytest-postgresql? And thanks for your comment.

Comment: @9769953 thanks, yes I did check. I checked as well for any extra db instance.

Comment: You can do transaction inside of transactions.